Whatever happened to Chessmaster?
It started off with CGA and then it supported EGA, and I thought it got very popular with each version. But around the year 2000 it just disappeared, and the Wikipedia article doesn't really say why. = =

I'm wondering because the new computers are a 1000 times faster than the ones that Chessmaster used to run on, and I wonder how well it plays.

Company went out of business?

It went up to Chessmaster Live on XBox 360 in 2008.

The latest version of Chessmaster for the PC was the 11th edition in 2007. By that time, the chessmaster engine had fallen behind significantly compared to other commercially available engines. (Of course, it'll still beat the vast majority of human players, but who'd buy the 15th-ranked engine when they could have one of the top5?)
Also, the option of playing online against human players has put a bit of a dent in all kinds of chess software.

The last Windows release was in 2007, and then XBox 360 in 2008 as Alan B says, so this is hardly retrocomputing.

@MichaelGraf Feel free to expand that a tad and post as an answer!

@StephenKitt: Chessmaster made its debut in the 1980s, which is certainly the "retrocomputing" era.  Whether a question is on topic shouldn't be dependent upon the answer unless the answer could be found extremely readily.

@supercat Sure, it should also depend on what the question asks for - in this case, why Chessmaster vanished after the naughties. That's clearly asking for a non retro event.

@Raffzahn: I think the interest in Chessmaster probably stems from the fact that it debuted in 1980, rather than the fact that it was maintained past the year 2000.  The observation that it had been maintained past 2000 to me shows some research effort, and seemed to be hoping for an answer like "The programmers left to join XX, which went on to develop the YY chess engine".

@supercat as Raffzahn says, the question is asking about events from the late 2000s. I’m not sure what the answer being readily available has anything to do with on-topicness — if a question is easy to answer (shows no research), it should be downvoted, but that doesn’t mean it’s off-topic. I tend to err towards keeping questions here (see my stances on Windows 2000 for example), but this question doesn’t cut it. Other questions about Chessmaster could well be on-topic of course, the series is indeed easily old enough for that.

Chessmaster was a video game. Chess has experienced a resurgence since Kasparov's two famous matches against Deep Blue, first dominating it, then losing to a mistake.
This turned computer chess from a simple video game into a competitive sport. Top players joined it, and they didn't just want to train against a punching bag anymore, they wanted a challenge. At the same time, internet was spreading fast, so you could always play another human online, in one click, which reduced the need for varied AI opponents.
Modern chess engines are significantly stronger. Chessmaster can be estimated at 2000-2700 elo on modern hardware, which is stronger than most players, but Stockfish is estimated at 3640.
Elo is a complicated rating. Low elos don't differ much, but it gets harder to earn as you grow. Past 2000, every 100 of Elo is a significant differentiator, with FIDE titles and other key levels at:

1800 - minimum for titles in age-restricted competitions
2000 - Women Candidate Master
2200 - Candidate Master
2300 - FIDE Master
2400 - International Master
2500 - Grandmaster
2600 - required peak over 9+ rounds to earn Grandmaster
2700 and higher are normally at least national champions
2750-2800 is normal for world championship candidates
Highest ratings ever were 2882 by Carlsen and 2851 by Kasparov

It usually takes a human player a year+ to go to the next title, 100 elo up, and many get stuck at one of these levels. There's been ~10,000 human players over 2300, ~2,000 over 2500, ~140 over 2700, and just 2 over 2800.
So the 3,640 of Stockfish vs the 2000-2,700 of Chessmaster is the equivalent of driving circles around another car. The difference between a souped-up Supra and a jet fighter (they accelerate faster too). Chessmaster could qualify for a championship, but Stockfish is at "resistance is futile" level, having beaten Hikaru, currently the 2nd strongest human player, with pawn odds.
The Chessmaster game's AI can still beat most human players, except for titled professionals. But it can't compete against modern engines, even if Chessmaster was given a Ryzen 9950X3D and Stockfish was restricted to the smallest single-core SoC that can run it. Even with a single-core CPU, top 10 modern engines play in the 3500+ range.

Women have a separate, lower, score range?

@RonJohn There are Women's titles that are given at a slightly lower elo numbers. But they are separate titles, such as WCM up to WGM. On average, women are ~100 elo behind men. And computers, ~800 ahead...

I have Chessmaster 3000 and 4000. Given that it's a 16 bit Windows application, getting it running directly on modern hardware sounds like quite the undertaking. I could throw it on qemu but for once it's actually going to matter unlike most software that old.

@Joshua The Grandmaster Edition (2008) can run on WMware with a Win7 guest OS. I find the 2700 result suspect, but it's definitely over 2,000 on a single Ryzen core.

@Therac: You're running a much newer version.

Chess is not a sport.

@Atario Then neither is golf, lacrosse, counter-strike, air rifle, or baseball.

@Therac Counter-strike is indeed not a sport; nothing you can do from your couch is a sport.  However, I'd love to hear why you think chess not being one disallows all the others you mentioned.

@Atario The debate about what is and isn't a sport is as old as sport itself. If one draws the line at aiming a physical rifle vs a digital one, then live and online chess will be on different sides of it. What matters in our context is that chess has globally-recognized regulations, governing bodies and ratings. And so, now, does computer chess. Chessmaster's engine was built for entertainment, modern ones for competition.

@Therac Wall Street has globally-recognized regulations, governing bodies, and ratings too. Does that make stock trading a sport? It's disingenuous and dissolving the meanings of words to give anything that's simply a competition or a game the classification "sport", no matter how organized it may be. The word "game" exists for a reason. As well, the criterion you gave disallows anything from being a sport that's not also a big enterprise. The real distinction between a sport and a non-sport game is whether you have a decent chance of being injured or killed by playing it.

@Atario Ah. Then golf's out, Pokemon Go's in.

@Therac People regularly get injured (and on occasion even killed) playing golf — the injury rate is higher than for rugby, in fact.  And, indeed, I'd be far more inclined to call Pokemon Go a sport than I would chess or Counter-Strike.
